# What is the sampling distribution

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
S& P(S) \\ \hline
 \{1,3,5,6\}& \frac{1}{8} \\ \hline
 \{2,3,7,8\}&\frac{1}{4} \\ \hline
 \{1,4,6,8\}& \frac{1}{8} \\ \hline
\{2,4,6,8\}& \frac{3}{8} \\ \hline
 \{4,5,7,8\}& \frac{1}{8} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Find the probability of selection $\pi_i$ for each unit $i$.
$\pi_i= \sum_j^ P(S_j)$.

\begin{align}
\text{So } \pi_1 & = \frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{4} \\[10pt]
\pi_2 & = \frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{8}=\frac{5}{8} \\[10pt]
\pi_3 & = \frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{8} \\[10pt]
\pi_4 & = \frac{1}{8}+\frac{3}{8}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{5}{8} \\[10pt]
\pi_5 & = \frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{4} \\[10pt]
\pi_6 & = \frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{3}{8}=\frac{5}{8} \\[10pt]
\pi_7 & = \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{3}{8} \\[10pt]
\pi_8 & = \frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{3}{8}=\frac{7}{8}
\end{align}

What is the sampling distribution of    $\hat{t}=8\bar{y}$
I'm stuck on this part, $\bar{y}$ is the sample mean, so i have to find the mean of $S$, and then multiply it by $8$ to get 
$\hat{t}$ right?
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
S&P(S)&\bar{y}&\hat{t}=\bar{y}*8 \\ \hline
 \{1,3,5,6\}& \frac{1}{8}& 3.75&30 \\ \hline
 \{2,3,7,8\}&\frac{1}{4}& 5&40 \\ \hline
 \{1,4,6,8\}& \frac{1}{8}& 4.75&38 \\ \hline
\{2,4,6,8\}& \frac{3}{8}& 5& 40\\ \hline
 \{4,5,7,8\}& \frac{1}{8}& 6&48 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Supposedly solution: $$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Sample number}&\text{Sample} S_i & \text{Sampled Observations}& P(S_i)&\hat{t}=\bar{y}*8 \\ \hline
 1&\{1,3,5,6\}&1& 4& 7& 7 & \frac{1}{8}&38 \\ \hline
 2&\{2,3,7,8\}&2&4& 7&8&\frac{1}{4}& 42 \\ \hline
 3&\{1,4,6,8\}&1 &4& 7&8& \frac{1}{8} & 40 \\ \hline
4&\{2,4,6,8\}&2 &4& 7& 8& \frac{3}{8}& 42\\ \hline
5& \{4,5,7,8\}&4& 7& 7&8& \frac{1}{8}& 52 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

I don't know how they got different $\hat{t}$.

Comment: Yes that looks right

Comment: But to get $\hat{t}$ do I need to get the sample mean from mean?

Comment: Huh? I said what you're doing looks right. So just add another column that's the $\bar y$ column times eight

Comment: Gotcha, let me do it right now.

Comment: Ok looks right, do you consider your answer complete now (I do) or do you have questions?

Comment: The second and fourth column of the table are the sampling distribution. If your book gives you something else best include that in the question.

Comment: I'll put the solution then, thanks for the help @spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: No idea what half those columns mean ( and you didn't seem to label things right) so maybe there's something there.

Comment: so there's no way of telling how they got different numbers than me? Like 38 and I got 30.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66034/discussion-between-spaceisdarkgreen-and-killercamin).